# laravel 5.6 id is automatically casted to int

Tags: laravel, casting, laravel-5.6

I'm using Laravel 5.6 with the following table structure:

```
public function up() {
        Schema::create( 'traffic', function ( Blueprint $table ) {
            $table->string( 'id' );
            $table->unsignedInteger( 'category_id' );
            $table->unsignedInteger( 'magnitude_id' );
            $table->unsignedInteger( 'start_id' )->nullable();
            $table->unsignedInteger( 'destination_id' )->nullable();
            $table->unsignedInteger('locale_id');
            $table->integer( 'length' )->comment( 'in metres' );
            $table->integer( 'delay' )->comment( 'in seconds' );
            $table->decimal( 'position_lat', 10, 8 );
            $table->decimal( 'position_lon', 10, 8 );
            $table->timestamps();
})
```

When I dump a single record, laravel has converted the `id` field to an integer:

```
Traffic {#351 ▼
  #casts: array:1 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: false
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:13 [▼
    "id" => 3
    "category_id" => 6
    "magnitude_id" => 3
    "start_id" => 1898
    "destination_id" => 1898
    "locale_id" => 3
    "length" => 3650
    "delay" => 3061
    "position_lat" => "5.27669000"
    "position_lon" => "51.85458000"
    "created_at" => "2018-03-21 15:55:13"
    "updated_at" => "2018-03-21 15:55:13"
    "name" => "nl"
  ]
  #original: array:13 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: array:10 [▶]
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
```

In my model I have added the following without any luck:

```
class Traffic extends Model {

    protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'string'
    ];
```

From what I've found so far this should be the way to cast the `id` field to type string. So I'm either doing something wrong or this is a bug.
Any ideas on how I could solve this?

I know it wold probably be solved if I created an integer field `id` or rename the current field to something else. But I'm hoping there is a better solution.

Comment: have you add this `public $incrementing = false;`.. need to be disable i think

Comment: Or you can set `protected $keyType = 'string';`. The default is `int`.

Comment: Actually the `protected $casts = ['id' => 'string']` works just fine. You're not seeing it because you used `dd($model)` and looked at `attributes` property, which is just a copy of the database record before accessors are applied (including `$casts`).

Comment: `$incrementing = false` worked for me where `$keyType = 'string'` has not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [ZeroOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3319074/zeroone) mentioned:

> have you add this public $incrementing = false;.. need to be disable i
>   think

This worked for me.